# React simple REST API using basic authentication

Tags: reactjs, rest

I am trying to learn how to use react with rest and am stuck with debugging or at least to check what is going wrong. I have been following a tutorial and just replaced the values to fit my sample rest api response but am getting blank page.

my App.js

```
 class App extends Component {
      render() {
        return (
          <Products products={this.state.products} />
        )
      }   
      state = {
        products: []
      };

      componentDidMount() {
        var headers = new Headers();
        //test1:test1 is username and password
        headers.append("Content-Type", "application/json");
        headers.append("Authorization", "Basic " + base64.encode("myKey:myPass"));

        fetch('myURL', {headers: headers})
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then((data) => {
          this.setState({ products: data })
        })
        .catch(console.log)
      }

    }
```

my products.js

```
const Products = ({ products }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <center><h1>Products List</h1></center>
      {products.map((product) => (
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">{product.title}</h5>
            <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">{product.price}</h6>
            <p class="card-text">{product.id}</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  )
};

export default Products
```

my sample json response looks like this:

```
{
    "products": [
        {
            "title": "Cras Selma dress",
            "id": 4985,            
            "price": "1499",
        },
        {
            "title": "Selected Homme Aron suede jacket",
            "id": 4886,
            "price": "2700",

        }
    ]
}
```

my first guess is that its not getting the proper response or not handling the response. When i check my url via postman using basic authentication it all returns fine with all the details similar to my posted json response.

Comment: Hi, could you check the network tab to see whether there are any issues, or something irregular with the call?

Comment: oh good catch so it says:
Access to fetch at 'https://about-ourstory.se/wc-api/v3/products' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I now know that you are having a CORS problem (discussed in the comments of the question.). There a few ways to solve it, the proper way would depend on what kind of server you are using.

If you are using *Node.js*:

`app.use(cors())`

would be enough, learn more: https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html

Other than that, if you want a quick fix, there are Chrome extensions to help you:
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-cors-access-control/lhobafahddgcelffkeicbaginigeejlf

So, the problem is not in your code, but in the CORS, on which you can learn more here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS.

Another quick solution for CORS is, `https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/`

You append this before your actual API, something like this:

```
const MY_API = 'http://localhost:8080/api/items';

const FULL_API = `https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/${MY_API}`;

axios.get(FULL_API);
```

Nevertheless, I would highly recommend googling how to solve CORS problem with the backend you are using.

Comment: Thank you .. this moves me forward will read up on the sources.